# Filter on http get response- angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="dat in details | filter : { dat.product_name : textname}">
    <hr/>
    <p style="color:#4C97C8;" class="lead"><strong>{{dat.product_name}}</strong></p>                                
</div>
```

is i am doing any mistake?

Comment: Yes the syntax is `filter: { product_name: textname }`. Leave out `dat` in the filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `.dat` prefix in `filter: {dat.product_name : textname}`.

---

```
<div ng-repeat="dat in details | filter: {product_name : textname}">
    <hr/>
    <p style="color:#4C97C8;" class="lead"><strong>{{dat.product_name}}</strong></p>
    <ul>
        <li><b>Product:</b><span> {{dat.product_name}}</span></li>
        <li><b>Product Manager:</b><span> {{dat.first_name}}{{dat.last_name}}</span></li>
        <li><b>Product Line:</b><span> {{dat.productline_name}}</span></li>
    </ul>                               
</div>
```